# How to check whether a given key is in a map structure in CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to update a value stroed in map of given key using cql. Can anyone tell me how to do it? The following is my table:

```
create table game(game_id uuid, game_name text, participant_id_name map<uuid, text>, PRIMARY KEY (game_id));
create index on game(participant_id_name);
```

Now I have a given participant's uuid and want to update his/her name, but I dont know the game_id. I wonder how can I check if the participant belongs to participant_id_name column and then update the name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cassandra query on Map - Contains Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473747/cassandra-query-on-map-contains-clause)

Comment: @uri2x Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe your data model is optimal given what you are trying to do, so I am proposing the following:

```
create table game(game_id uuid, game_name text, participant_id int, participant_id_name text, PRIMARY KEY (game_id), participant_id);
```

With this table, you have a partition key of game_id and a clustering column of participant_id, so the partition will include everything for the game_id ordered by the participant_id column.  I believe this makes sense for what you are trying to do.  Instead of using a database generated unique id for the participant_id, I suggest having the application provide an integer when inserting the name of the person so you know both pieces of data.

(Please note I do not have complete information, and am making a best effort with the information provided.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help :)I think your recommendation is better than what I had. Could you elaborate why using   PRIMARY KEY (game_id), participant_id) is better than using map type? Thanks.

Comment: I'm making a best guess, to be honest.  You should read this: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling and think about the queries you want to perform.  That should help build a data model.  Its possible a map will be fine but designing with a requirement to read-then-write is a definite anti-pattern to avoid.

Comment: Thanks very much for your link!